# ASP.NET C# Passing data from a variable into a select list as the selected value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am hoping someone can help me.  I have been trying for quite some time now and cannot seem to find the answer.

I have a .cshtml page and have retrieved a value from a SQL table and passed it into a variable.  I am able to populate a text box with the value with the below.

```
<input type="text" id="priority" name="Priority" value="@priority">
```

However, I would like to pass the value contained in the variable to a select list and not a text box.  I have tried the below, but it does not work.

```
<select id="priority" name="Priority" value="@priority" >
    <option value="">Please choose...</option>
    <option value="Low">Low</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="High">High</option>
</select>
```

I am aware that I can put @priority within the  tag, but that would then make 2 entries of the same value appear in the list.

I would like the user to be able to have the choice of either leaving the select list as the same value as the variable or choosing from any of the other options in the list.

Can anyone help me with this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the Razor syntax, you can directly write something like this (i wrote it directly in this window without an editor so excuse if i missed a brace or something):

```
<select id="priority" name="Priority" value="@priority" >
   <option value="">Please choose...</option>
   <option @{if(priority.Equals("Low")){<text>selected</text>}} value="Low">Low</option>
   <option @{if(priority.Equals("Medium")){<text>selected</text>}} value="Medium">Medium</option>
   <option @{if(priority.Equals("High")){<text>selected</text>}} value="High">High</option>
</select>
```

Or if using a model you can use the Html.DropDownListFor method

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are not using a strongly typed model you can use the html dropdown list function.

```
@Html.DropDownList("priority", new []
{
    new SelectListItem(){ Selected = false, Text = "Please choose . . .", Value=""},
    new SelectListItem(){ Selected = (priority == "High"), Text = "High", Value = "High"},
    new SelectListItem(){ Selected = (priority == "Medium"), Text = "Medium", Value = "Medium"},
    new SelectListItem(){ Selected = (priority == "Low"), Text = "Low", Value = "Low"}
})
```